# How can I traverse a multidimensional array using an array of keys?

Tags: php

Let's say I have an arbitrary array of keys:

```
$keys = array('foo', 'bar', 'baaz');
```

I'd like to use that array of keys to traverse a multidimensional array `$values` such that each element in the `$keys` array is one level of the `$values` array. For example, given the `$keys` array above, I'm looking for the equivalent of:

```
$values['foo']['bar']['baaz']
```

or:

```
$values[$keys[0]][$keys[1]][$keys[2]]
```

But I won't know what's in the `$keys` array or how large it is, so I couldn't hard code it like this.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$value = $values;
foreach ($keys as $key) {
    $value = $value[$key];
}
echo $value;
```

Comment: *facepalm* of course! And if I wanted to use it for assignment, it should be as simple as adding a reference operator to `$value[$key]`, right?